# $.on("mouseenter") lags my website when I have a lot of Dynamically generated div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am doing a graduation website for my school. On each tab I will ajax call all the works to display, once the works got displayed, I got a function

```
    $(".viewport-computer .img_thumb_holder").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            //stuff to do on mouse enter
            $(this).find(".caption").stop().fadeTo('slow', 1); 
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            //stuff to do on mouse leave
            $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);  
            $(".caption").stop().fadeTo('slow', 0); 
            $(".viewport-computer .img_thumb_holder .img_thumb").stop().fadeTo(1, 1);  
            $(".viewport-computer .img_thumb").hide();
        }
    });
```

which allows me to hover on the works and display the `name` and `caption` of the works displayed.

This works fine if the ajax call appended 20 or lesser works. But when I have more than 20 works, there will be a significant lag feeling when you hover over the works, where the transition to show the `name` and `caption` only show after like 3 seconds after hovering. I am quite stressed on how I can solve the lag issues as initially I was using

```
$(".viewport-computer .img_thumb_holder").hover(function(){
        //$(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.4);  
        $(this).find(".caption").stop().fadeTo('slow', 1); 
    },function(){  
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);  
        $(".caption").stop().fadeTo('slow', 0); 
        $(".viewport-computer .img_thumb_holder .img_thumb").stop().fadeTo(1, 1);  
        $(".viewport-computer .img_thumb").hide();
    });
```

but I changed it to .on(mouseenter) after online searching that i should use .on but it doesn't solve the issues. Any other advice will be appreciated

Update - to show my codings on how I display it

HTML:

```
            <div class="row">
                <!-- For mobile viewport -->
                <div class="viewport-mobile img_thumb_holder_div col-xs-12 hidden-lg">
                </div>

                <!-- For computer viewport -->
                <div class="viewport-computer img_thumb_holder_div col-lg-12 visible-lg no-padding ">

                </div>
             </div>
```

JS - once this tab is clicked, it will display all works

```
            $(".tab_bm").click(function() {
                $(".container .popUp .author_pic_holder img").css("border-color", "#006a96");  
                $(".divider").css("background-image", "url(images/divider_it.png)"); 
                $(".infinite_header img").attr("src", "images/header_it.png");
                $(document.body).css("background-image", "url(images/BG/BlueBG.jpg)"); 
                $(".footer img").attr("src", "images/Footer_v1_1.jpg");
                //remove all div images first before adding images
                resetHome(); // this remove all the previously added displayed works
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "CMS/PHP/displayBmThumbs.php",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $(".viewport-computer .img_thumb_holder").remove();
                        $(".viewport-mobile .img_thumb_holder").remove();
                        $(".author_pic_holder").show();
                        $(".author_info_holder").show();
                        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                            $(".viewport-computer.img_thumb_holder_div").append("<div class='col-lg-2 img_thumb_holder no-padding bioDisplay'><div class='featured'></div><img class='img_thumb'><h2 class='caption'>Author<br />Description</h2></div>");
                            $(".viewport-mobile.img_thumb_holder_div").append("<div class='col-xs-6 img_thumb_holder top-buffer bioDisplay'><img class='img_thumb'><h2 class='caption_mobile'>Author<br />Description</h2></div>");
                        }
                        idArray = [];
                        captionArray = [];
                        $('.viewport-computer .img_thumb_holder img').each(function(index, element) {
                            // Work out the data to set

                            // Now apply this to the elements
                            if (data[index]){
                                var imageUrl = data[index].links;
                                var captionHtml = "<span>" + toTitleCase(data[index].caption) + "<span class='spacer'></span><br/>"
                                $(element).attr("src", imageUrl);
                                if(checkIfCom == true){
                                    $(element).parent().css('background-image', 'url("'+imageUrl+'")');
                                }
                                $(element).next().html(captionHtml);
                                captionArray.push(toTitleCase(data[index].caption));
                                idArray.push(data[index].id);
                                homeLinksArray.push(data[index].links);
                                //homeTitleArray.push(toTitleCase(data[index].title));
                            }                       
                            $('.viewport-mobile .img_thumb_holder img').each(function(index, element) {
                                var imageUrl = homeLinksArray[index];
                                var captionHtml = captionArray[index];
                                $(element).attr("src", imageUrl); // i must find a way to solve this
                                $(element).next().html(captionHtml);

                            });
                            console.log("id: " + idArray);
                            console.log("caption: " + captionArray);
                            console.log("homeLinksArray: " + homeLinksArray );
                            hideDefault()
                            captionHover();
                            clickToAuthorPage();
                        });
                     }
                });
            });
```

and lastly

my current mouseEnter/mouseLeave function

```
function captionHover() {       
    $(".viewport-computer .img_thumb_holder").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            //stuff to do on mouse enter
            $(this).find(".caption").stop().fadeTo('slow', 1); 
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            //stuff to do on mouse leave
            $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);  
            $(this).find(".caption").stop().fadeTo('slow', 0);
            //$(".caption").stop().fadeTo('slow', 0); 
            $(".viewport-computer .img_thumb_holder .img_thumb").stop().fadeTo(1, 1);  
            $(".viewport-computer .img_thumb").hide();
        }
    });
};
```

The delay isn't so bad now but u can still notice a 0.5 delay, any more ways I can improved it to work more efficiently?

Comment: Can we see the HTML, please? 3 seconds sounds like too much, but you are doing things quite inefficiently, especially in the `mouseleave` handler. You should consider reading the [`.on()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Comment: Could you provide a sandboxed example? Also it sounds like you might be able to do it just in CSS.

Comment: You only need to use `.on()` instead of `.hover()` if the elements you're binding to are loaded dynamically. But you're not using the delegation syntax of `.on()`, so that doesn't apply.

Comment: The caption look up can be optimized, for the rest we need to see your markup, but i'm not sure if that is enough to cause lag, try this, hardcode 50 or more items (no ajax loaded) in your markup, does that make them lag? What are the specs of your pc? If they do not lag, then the issue is somewhere else, maybe ghost nodes

Answer (score 2):

Can cut down a lot of unnecessary animation on all elements by targeting the ones that are isolated to the instance

In the mouseenter you target the instance of `.caption` but in mouseleave you target all of them in the page

Try

```
$(".viewport-computer .img_thumb_holder").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse enter
        $(this).find(".caption").stop().fadeTo('slow', 1); 
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse leave

        var $this = $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
        $this.find(".caption").stop().fadeTo('slow', 0);
        /* not sure where these are , perhaps this can be optimized also*/
        $(".viewport-computer .img_thumb_holder .img_thumb").stop().fadeTo(1, 1);  
        $(".viewport-computer .img_thumb").hide();
    }
});
```

Seeing the associated markup would be very helpful

Comment: nice, this did indeed smoothen the process abit, now it just a really minor delay showing, i'd say 0.5 seconds, sec let me post my code.

Comment: Create a demo in jsfiddle.net also if you can

Comment: wow.. i removed $(".viewport-computer .img_thumb_holder .img_thumb").stop().fadeTo(1, 1);  
            $(".viewport-computer .img_thumb").hide(); and everything became smooth. No more delays